# PyroCMS Geocoder Field Type Plugin Error

Tags: plugins, geocoding, pyrocms

This field type is awesome, but I can't get it to work.

I save a record to the database, only the address is saved.  The database column looks like it is saved in json format, but my records do not have a lat or lon value.

Then I display the data on a page and I get an error that lat and lon are null values.  The error occurs in field.geocoder.php line 88.

Has anyone used the geocoder plugin before?  Is lat and lon being saved in your database?

I am using pyro pro 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!  https://github.com/HighwayofLife/PyroStreams-Geocoder-Field-Type/issues/7

From twoplers:

To fix, change lines 60-61 in geocoder.js

FROM:

'lat': loc.jb,
'lng': loc.kb,
TO:

'lat': loc.ob,
'lng': loc.pb,
Hope this helps.